# how to select * group by in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model: Syscheck(PostgreSQL table name: syscheck_syscheck), include some fields

```
changes, size, uid, gid, filepath, syscheck_path
```

How can I perform a SQL query like this

```
SELECT * FROM syscheck_syscheck GROUP BY filepath
```

I have tried:

```
Syscheck.objects.values('filepath').annotate(Count('filepath'))
```

It worked, but only filepath field return, when I want more fields return, I tried this:

```
Syscheck.objects.values('filepath', 'size', 'uid', 'gui').annotate(Count('filepath'))
```

It didn't work

Comment: When you have a group of `Syscheck` objects with the same `filepath`, what is suppose the database to return for `'size', 'uid', 'gui'` since they will be different for each `syscheck`?

Comment: you can't use aggregate functions on `select *`

Comment: @Todor In template, I want to display all fields of Syscheck objects.

Comment: @alfonso.kim so there is no way to archive it

Answer (score 0):

Django ORM's group by is a little bit tricky. it only do it if you group by the "base" model.
I managed that situation making that kind of queries like this:

```
Filepath.objects.all().select_related('syscheck').filter(syscheck__isnull=False).annotate(Count('filepath'))
```

You can access to the `syscheck` data but it will depends on your situation.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What happened? Maybe you could use the Count annotation. I've edited my answer.